# "in his own mind", "in one's own mind" phrase

Tags: phrases

In an investing book I read, I came across the phrase "in his own mind" a few times. examples:
...the investor should be satisfied in his own mind that the location and type of the building.... "

"...and he will probably be uncertain in his own mind as to whether he is at bottom a stockholder or a bondholder..."

"the actual purchase of any such issues must require also that the purchaser be satisfied in his own mind that the prospects of the enterprise are .... "

I couldn't find in any dictionary what is the meaning of the phrase "in his own mind" or "in one's own mind" in this context. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In other words, the investor needs to be a critical thinker, and come to their own conclusions [based on all available evidence](https://www.sec.gov/reportspubs/investor-publications/investorpubsaskquestionshtm.html). The investor takes on risk when they purchase stocks or other instruments, and they alone are responsible for any negative outcomes. Many investors do rely on advice from others, but even so, the decision is theirs and theirs alone.

Comment: Yes. The PP in 'satisfied in his own mind' is redundant – a person can't be satisfied/convinced _other than_ in their [own] cognitive facility – but very valuable and one could say almost obligatory as an emphasiser here.